# During run time add or remove tabs in Tablayout with Fragmentpageradapter?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have implemented TablLayout with FragmentPagerAdapter, I would like to add or remove Tabs but I am unsure how to implement this. I have searched for this but couldn't find it all other examples are similar but not the same as I am not using an arraylist and quite get my head around the tutorials.

This is the FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int tabCount;

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabCount = numberOfTabs;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                Tab1Fragment tab1 = new Tab1Fragment();
                return tab1;

            case 1:
                Tab2Fragment tab2 = new Tab2Fragment();
                return tab2;

            case 2:
                Tab3Fragment tab3 = new Tab3Fragment();
                return tab3;

            case 3:
                Tab4Fragment tab4 = new Tab4Fragment();
                return tab4;

            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

This is the activity

```
public class TabLayoutDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_layout_demo);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_low_battery));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 4 Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));


        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout
                .getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tab_layout_demo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am using the support TabLayout and Viewpager , from what I know addition and removal of tab is to be done from the adapter class, so i tried to use this code but I can't figure out what is tablItems here referring to and how to set up this variable or is there any other way to do this ?

```
public void removeTabPage(int position) {
    if (!tabItems.isEmpty() && position<tabItems.size()) {
          tabItems.remove(position);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```